# What does this syntax do in php ->{}

Tags: php, syntax

I just saw this syntax in an application that I am reading through:

```
$this->CI->{$this->user_table}->selectEmail()
```

I've never seen the `->{}` syntax before.

What does that do?

Comment: It just dawned on me that is probably a way to pass in a variable in the chain. Is that correct?

Comment: It is a way of encapsulation expressions. First $this->user_table gets evaluated and then the other command with the value of $this->user_table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It lets php know you want to use the resulting value as a name. For instance if the value of `$this->user_table` is `users` it tries to access the property of `$this->CI->users`, otherwise you would get an error trying to access it. [This](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) Might be helpful they are called 'Variable Variables' apparently.